# Server has phpmyadmin setup, but does not require a password to access

Tags: password-protected

Our company has recently taken over a website job. The site is riddled with security holes that I'm painstakingly patching.

One of the issues is that the previous developer set up phpMyAdmin but did not require a password to access it. I have access to the folder where phpMyAdmin is installed through FTP, but do not have access to the database via the control panel from the host. How can I make sure that the same password used to access the database through a script is also the password used to access the database through phpMyAdmin. Is this usually done through htaccess or is there another method?

TLDR: phpMyAdmin installed locally but no password is required to get to it. How do I get the folder password protected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`config.inc.php` is the configuration file for phpMyAdmin.  You are likely using [`config`](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Auth_types#config) based authentication.

You can change this to `cookie` based authentication, which will allow you to authentication against the usernames and passwords stored in your MySQL database.  Specify this under the `auth_type` setting.

You also must specify `blowfish_secret`, which is used by cookie based authentication to encrypt the password in the cookie.  Put it near the top of the configuration before the servers start getting specified.

```
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'anythingShorterThan42(?)characters';
```

Comment: okay, that seems to be leading me down the right path, but now I get the following error when I access the site: The configuration file now needs a secret passphrase.